# 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Token }' when trying to access a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I have a function that populates multiple buttons, each with their own onclick function:

```
$("#event_list").append(
          "<button type='button' onClick='showInfo("+i+",'"+name+"')'> Event:<br>"+events_arr[i][2]+"<br> Organizer:<br>"+events_arr[i][1]+"</button>"
        );
```

The function showInfo is defined elsewhere in the file (i is a number, name is a string)

```
function showInfo(i, name)
{
  console.log("showInfo works");
  //makeTable12(i, name);
  //makeTable24(i);
}
```

Whenever I click on any of these buttons, Chrome throws an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }` 
I can't figure out why it does that. Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: create a fiddle and link your question to it

Comment: I strongly recommend a static code analyser like eslint to help spot and diagnose these issues. Especially if you use a plugin for your IDE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you wrapped the `onclick` content with single quote `'` you should wrap the arguments of the function with double-quotes (but note that you should escape them):

```
 onClick='showInfo("+i+",\""+name+"\")'
```

Check the following snippet:

```js
i = 0;
name = 'test';
events_arr = [['', '', '']];
$("#event_list").append(
  "<button type='button' onClick='showInfo("+i+",\""+name+"\")'> Event:<br>"+events_arr[i][2]+"<br> Organizer:<br>"+events_arr[i][1]+"</button>"
);

function showInfo(i, name)
{
  console.log("showInfo works");
  //makeTable12(i, name);
  //makeTable24(i);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="event_list"></div>
```

Comment: Good answer. Additionally, if working in ES6, you can use template literal syntax to make the variable interpolation a bit easier, like this:

`const myHtml = \`<button type='button' onClick='showInfo(${i},"${name}")'></button>\`;`

Comment: @DuncanThacker I would actually change the `onclick` to a `$(...).click(func)` in order to avoid such problems :) this would be the first thing I would change...

Comment: Indeed - and create the element using jQuery modifications instead of string building for protection against injection attacks!